# Help on a list manipulating list

Tags: list, haskell, syntax

Hi  I am a newbie in Haskell.
I am trying to do a simple task.

```
test :: (RealFloat a) => a -> a  ->  [a]  
test xs ys= [ w : h: [] | w  <- xs, h <- ys]
```

I am getting an error here. (with out a doubt) 
In this task, I am simply trying to bind two lists (ex: test [12.12] [14.14])
and hopefully return a new combined list (ex: [12.12,14.14])

thanks for your help

Comment: `[12.12] ++ [14.14] = [12.12,14.14]`

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "bind"?

Answer (score 3):

Your signature is wrong.  Try:

```
test xs ys = ...
```

then in ghci:

```
> :t test
test :: [t] -> [t] -> [[t]]
```

You need two arguments, both are lists, not two arguments of single elements.

Comment: He's looking to concatenate two lists, not combine them into a list of lists. Your signature should be test :: [t] -> [t] -> [t]

Comment: If he said concatenate then there'd be no doubt, but the term `bind` is ambiguous to me.  At any rate, I believe he is here as a result of a type error when running the provided code - even if it isn't the code he wants perhaps he will benefit by learning type signatures and `:t` in GHCi.

Answer (score 3):

Drakosha is correct. List concatenation already has an operator in Haskell.

```
test :: (RealFloat a) => [a] -> [a]  ->  [a]  
test xs ys= xs ++ ys
```

You probably don't want to use a list comprehension here, unless you want to extract every element in your first and second list and do something with them. For example, a Cartesian Product:

```
list1 = [1.0,1.1,1.2] :: [Double]
list2 = [2.0,2.1,2.2] :: [Double]

testComps xs ys = [(x,y) | x <- xs, y <- ys]
```

Or addition:

```
testComps2 xs ys = [ x + y | x <- xs, y <- ys]
```

Or even creating lists:

```
testComps3 xs ys = [x : y  : [] | x <- xs, y <- ys]
```

In GHCi, this will yield the following:

```
*Main> testComps list1 list2
[(1.0,2.0),(1.0,2.1),(1.0,2.2),(1.1,2.0),(1.1,2.1),(1.1,2.2),(1.2,2.0),(1.2,2.1)
    ,(1.2,2.2)]
*Main> testComps2 list1 list2
[3.0,3.1,3.2,3.1,3.2,3.3000000000000003,3.2,3.3,3.4000000000000004]
*Main> testComps3 list1 list2
[[1.0,2.0],[1.0,2.1],[1.0,2.2],[1.1,2.0],[1.1,2.1],[1.1,2.2],[1.2,2.0],[1.2,2.1]
    ,[1.2,2.2]]
```

The weird results in testComps2 is, of course, normal cruft when you're dealing with floating-point numbers. In the real world you'd compensate for this by rounding.

Another problem you'll run into is the difference between (++) and (:). Simply put, (:) tacks individual items onto a list, whereas (++) concatenates two lists.

Answer (score 1):

You need list concatenation:

```
[12.12] ++ [14.14]

=> [12.12,14.14]
```

Comment: This is wrong  `test [1,2] [3,4] == [[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4]]` not `[1,2,3,4]`.  Based on his words that _might_ be what he wants, but his words are unclear while is code is precise.

Comment: @TomMD: The code (sand type signature) is precise and gives a result that *might* be valid, but he's clearly a beginner and doesn't know how list comprehensions work. On the other hand, his example was also clear and he sure speaks English longer than Haskell ;)